# NancyFx how to remove the tumbeast from errors

Tags: nancy

I do like the NancyFX error custom page. Unfortunately an exigent customer prefer not to see the green monster besides the error. Is there some way to just remove the image from the almost perfect nancyfx error message page?

Comment: Do you *really* want to be without [tumbeasts](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/state_web_summer#tumblr)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You implement an `IStatusCodeHandler` and handle the status codes you want (like 404 and 500) by returning a response for them. If you need to render a view, take a dependency on the `IViewRenderer` and off you go =)

Comment: well, I read about IStatusCodeHanlder, but I lke the NancyFX behavior at 100% apart tumbeast...